# How to include external scripts in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.5/socket.io.js"></script>
```

How to include external library in node.js.

I need to include the below library in nodejs client file(.js file).

Comment: have you installed in your project using `npm` or `bower` ?

Comment: Seems a duplicate of this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641631/how-to-import-external-library-to-nodejs

Comment: Yes aatif-bandey. In my Nodejs Server i have installed npm. Nodejs Client running on a device. There is some limitation in client side to install NPM. So i'm going to include libraries in Client end.

Answer (score 1):

Socket.io comes with two components, an NPM module and a client-side script.

Install the NPM module but running this in the console:

```
npm install socket.io
```

Docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io

And then put the client-side script inside your view template, see docs: http://socket.io/download/

Answer (score 0):

you can download it and require it locally `(require('./socket.io.js')).`
The best way would be to find it on npm and install it like any other node module using the `npm install` command and then require it like `require('npmModuleName')`

For your file here is the npm link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io.

You can install it like `npm install socket.io` and use it like

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.on('connection', function(socket){});
io.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple explaination:
nodejs uses a module system. This means that you can use the command line to include new modules in your application:

```
npm init
npm install socket.io
```

This will make a package.json and node_modules in your project and now you can include the module.

In your application you can use the installed module with a require statement

```
var io = require(socket.io)
```

Now you can just use socket.io like you did before, but before you continue you might want to read up into nodejs, modules and npm.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs.

Socket.IO consists of two parts: [Server API](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/) and [Client API](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/)

To **install Server API** part you need to install it using [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/). Installation is pretty simple:

```
npm install socket.io --save
```

And then import it, where you need (example for ES6):

```
import IO from 'socket.io'
let socket = IO(`http://localhost:8000`)
```

For **client side**, there is few options.

Load and include from CDN:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

If you are using bower, you can install socket.io-client:

```
bower install socket.io-client --save
```

and then import it like this:

```
<script src="/bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Also you can download [this file](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/socket.io.js) directly to your project and import it, but it won't a best way...