# How to use external JS library methods in my Node.JS project if this library does not exist in NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, require

I have a problem which can be easily solved by importing an `external JS library` into `Node.js`. However, this library does not exist in `NPM`.

I found out an old [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641631/how-to-import-external-library-to-nodejs) on `StackOverflow` which seems to fix the problem. However, it looks wierd.

Is there **a more convenient** solution in 2k20 to use `external JS library` methods into my `Node.js` code?

Comment: And the library is.... ?

Comment: @JoseGuzman, each external library you usually add into `src` of `<script>` but not represented in NPM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If your library have a `package.json`: You can install the package directly from the git repository, for example `npm install https://github.com/vendor-creator/vendor-package`. **NOTE** that for this method to work, in cases where the module has to be built, the git repository should contain a `dist/` folder containing the built code **or** have in its `package.json`, a [`prepare`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) step responsible for building the package upon installation.
- If your library **does not** have a `package.json` and is simply a vanilla JavaScript file like the [Lodash JavaScript file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js), I would advise just like in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641631/how-to-import-external-library-to-nodejs) you linked, to create a `vendor.js` file *(`.min` if the script is minified)*, copy and paste the content of the file and `require` it. **Be aware** that some libraries using [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) and not NPM, are designed for browser environment and may lack [CommonJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521471/relation-between-commonjs-amd-and-requirejs) support preventing you from using `require`. In that case you'll have to modify the library source code.

  If it's a small library, there is no need to create an advanced build system. If the library is stable, just copy and paste it and you'll be fine. When in doubt always follow the [K.I.S.S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle.